# How to loop through the raster layers and create a PNG for each?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer

In QGIS 2.8.1 I have a number of raster layers covering the same extent, but for each year 1975-2014 (times three categories).

I am creating one print composer for the extent, but I need to print multiple PNG's - one for each raster layer.

How do I loop through the raster layers and send an output PNG for each?
Should I produce a python script (help needed) or somehow use the Atlas generator?